# Eclipse Plugin --add-exports Java 16+

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, spring-tool-suite, java-16, google-java-format

Using the [google-java-format](https://github.com/google/google-java-format#eclipse) eclipse plugin works great when running Eclipse under Java 11, but when running on Java 16+, it fails with the following error:

[image: issue running code formatter]

Full error: `A save participant caused problems. The save participant 'Code Clean Up' caused an exception: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.google.googlejavaformat.java.JavaInput (in unnamed module @0x99c5646) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Tokens$TokenKind (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.parser to unnamed module @0x99c5646. See the error log for details.`

The google-java-formatter [does note](https://github.com/google/google-java-format#jdk-16) that when running on JDK 16+, you need to set the `--add-exports` flag when running the formatter, due to JEP-396 (strong encapsulation of JDK Internals).  What isn't clear is how to tell set `--add-exports` for Eclipse plugins.

Adding the following to `eclipse.ini` (or in my case `SpringToolSuite4.ini`) doesn't seem to help (not to mention it feels wrong since its not targetting that particular plugin).  Is there a different way to approach/fix this?

```
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--illegal-access=permit
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: So why not just stick to Java 11 or the Java 15 that is bundled with most of the current Eclipse downloads? Eclipse doesn't have to be running Java 16 to develop Java 16 code.

Comment: Can you provide a few steps how to reproduce the issue, starting from a fresh STS 4.12.0.RELEASE install? I just tried that version, dropped the google javaformat plugin into it and switched to that implementation in the preferences, but I don't see the error appearing.

Comment: Without explicitly setting the -vm in eclipse.ini (or SpringToolSuite4.ini), Eclipse seems to use the platform default (that set via JAVA_HOME).  In my case, I currently have that set to a JDK 17 instance, but I get the same experience on JDK 16.  If you have google-java-formatter set as the formatter, and do a format (right click -> source format, or the keyboard shortcut) it doesn't show an error, but also doesn't actually format anything (it silently errors, though maybe its in the eclipse logs somewhere).  In my case, I configured formatting as a Save Action, producing the error above

Answer (score 11):

Just like xDeyan said above, your eclipse.ini file must have the following lines below the -vmargs line

```
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED
```

This has been tested and works with JDK17

Comment: Reference here:
https://github.com/google/google-java-format#as-a-library

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still having this issue running on JDK 17, just add `=` between the `--add-exports` like so:

```
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Edit your file eclipse.ini with this arguments :

```html
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED
```